# Return all items with status == "retired"

Tags: sql-server

I need to select "ItemNames" from a SQL Server 2014 table that has a "Status" of retired. I have tried playing with GROUP BY a lot, but haven't been able to finalize the query. Any help is appreciated.

For example, here's the Table. I should only return A and B from the SQL query, since each of these has a row with status == Retired:

```
ItemName       Status    LastUpdated
=========     ========   ============
A              active
A              retired
B              active
B              active
B              retired
C              active
C              inactive
```

Comment: What about `select itemname from table where status='retired'`

Comment: You should include your current query so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: You really need to find a basic SQL tutorial and work your way through it. A simple SELECT with a WHERE clause is lesson 1. We're not here to tutor you.

Comment: Thanks guys! I guess I was trying to unnecessarily complicate things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the where clause:

```
   Select DISTINCT ItemName from YourTableName WHERE status = 'retired'
```

Comment: You don't need the GROUP BY.

Comment: I assumed from the question there is a need to only return A and B values distinctively, otherwise,  there is no need for the GROUP By.

Comment: There is no GROUP BY needed, because there is no aggregate function (SUM, AVG, MAX, MIN, COUNT) in the SELECT.

Comment: Yes I see your point, but assume a case where there are 4 rows with ItemName and Status equaling 'A' and 'retired' respectively, without using group by, the output will be 'A' , 'A', 'A' , 'A', 'B', and as the question said it should show only A and B, we could use either GROUP BY or Distinct to show only 'A', 'B' and eliminate duplicates, so it depends on the user need.

Comment: DISTINCT would be appropriate in that case, not GROUP BY. Again, there is no aggregation happening in the SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by to make distinct

Select ItemName From YourTable Where Status='Retired' Group by ItemName

Answer (score -1):

Try this code i guess it works well

```
SELECT itemname FROM Table WHERE (Status='retired' and ItemName='A' or ItemName='B')
```